# why Cell Header and Cell contents are not aligned in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have this xaml code:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="number" Binding="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=OneWay}" Width="70"  CanUserResize="False" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=ProcessingState}" Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>


            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

but when it shows on screen, it generate this view:

[image]

As can be seen, the cells are not aligned with header. How can I make them aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to centre the text in the cells, then you could use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SalesPeriods}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="number" Width="70" CanUserResize="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProcessingState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you prefer to use a `DataGridTextColumn`, then you could still achieve this goal using the `ElementStyle` property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="number" Binding="{Binding Path=Year, Mode=OneWay}" 
    Width="70" CanUserResize="False" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```